# Atributo Class muda quando selenium clica em cima

Tags: selenium-webdriver

Estou tentando criar um script com selenium que faz comentários em um tal post do instagram numa determinada quantidade de vezes. Mas me deparei com esse problema que é oque, quando o selenium clica na parte para escrever o comentário e enviá-lo, o conteúdo do atributo que eu usei para encontrar a parte que escreve os comentário, muda e eu não sei como resolver isso.

[image]

Essa é a linha de código que eu usei para encontrar o elemento que escreve os comentários no instagram.

Depois que eu inicio o programa tudo roda muito bem até chegar nessa parte que dá o seguinte erro
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

E eu já procurei sobre e não consegui encontrar uma solução pra ele, se puderem me ajudar irei agradeçar muito!

Answer (score -2):

Você pode utilizar algum parámetro fixo. Tente isso:

```
def comentário():
element = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//[@aria-label='Adicione um comentário...']")
element.click()
element.send_keys("Hello World")
```